# How to create custom listview for android with margins between 2 elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need to create an application with a list-view activity, but the elements in the list should be separated one from another and have more then one click option:

Here is the image:

[image]

so i can click on the on the task to see the task details and i can click on the left side of the task (the colored part) to change it's color, and this way to change it's priority

i would really appreciate if some one could provide me with a tutorial or additional reading information to creating such custom lists.

Comment: Put the link to the image and someone with the permission to add images will edit it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`divider` and `dividerHeight` property of the ListView can make space between your listview items:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
  android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>
```

You can find some tutorial on how to build an Android Listview with [Multiple Clickable Zones](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the Multiple Clickable Zones tutorial was a great deal of use to me, and I did implement a multi-tuch item list using it. i have an implementation of a row of my list but i have no ListView object inside my project. So i cant use the divider and the dividerHeight properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom xml layout for list item. and in a listview give  devider heght..
like i did here.

[image]

```
 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/lstContact"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/lay"
     android:divider="#0000"
     android:dividerHeight="6dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:background="#0000"
     android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
     android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can use this as the layout for your list row in your list adapter.
And you can acheive the spacing by increasing and decreasing the margin for the parent layout.
Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help but my row layout is far more complicated and changing the layout_mergin on the parent layout didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mention a shape.xml for each styling your row. And then in your row layout use an RelativeLayout for arranging the items. And make sure that you make the `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`  for each button you create there. First one will be an ImageButton.  [image]

This is what you can achieve. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sweety, I managed to achieve the desired result. you can see it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380383/change-listview-row-background-based-on-a-choice-from-other-activity